# Divergence measured from integral of minimums: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \min(p(x), q(x)) dx$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I was studying a particular machine learning algorithm (the [GeoGAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02894)) and although this isn't mentioned in the paper, it seems to be that under certain conditions, the algorithm is maximizing (over $p$) the following function between probability density functions $p$ and $q$:
$$D(p, q) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \min(p(x), q(x)) dx$$

This appears to be measuring some sort of divergence between $p$ and $q$: when $p=q$, it reaches its maximum possible value of 1, and when $p$ and $q$ have disjoint supports, it reaches its minimum possible value of 0.

Is there a name for this metric, or is it similar to any known divergences? I couldn't find anything that seemed related on Wikipedia. Has anybody studied it or could point to any places I could learn more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This measure is related to the [histogram intersection distance](https://books.google.ca/books?id=KQHdDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA397&dq=histogram%20intersection%20distance%20swain%20ballard&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbxI3t_ZnfAhUFKXwKHQa8B5oQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=histogram%20intersection%20distance%20swain%20ballard&f=false) and can be rewritten as
$$
D(p,q)=1-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|p(x)-q(x)|dx.
$$
$D(p,q)$ is a similarity measure and its maximization corresponds to the minimization of the $L^1$ distance between $p$ and $q$ (when $p$ and $q$ have disjoint supports, $D(p,q)=0$ and not $2$).

Comment: Ah I messed up my maximum and minimum values thanks for pointing it out!